# SharePoint Farm account gets "denied access" error when attempting to create a new site

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

When attempting to create new sites in a site collection logging in under the Farm Account Administrator - -- we a getting "Access denied' error.  This is a new message that occurred after working with Microsoft Support on an unrelated SQL DB issue.

The only change we are aware that was made was to add additional security  roles to the Farm Account.

Comment: What doe's the log files say?

Answer (score 0):

I executed the stsadm command `-o updatefarmcredentials...` with no luck then I ran IE as Administrator and low and behold it worked!!